# How can I Get all the rows of Gridview to be editable mode while selecting value in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, excel

I am having one dropdownlist , gridview and two buttons .update and save
on selecting the value of dropdown list all the rows of  gridview should change to edit mode  and after entering values must be saved in database so please help me ? using c# and asp.net

Comment: Share the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your DropDownList control placed inside the grid template?

Comment: @sandeep: Check [Change Gid to Edit Mode on Button Click] (http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/631162/edit-all-rows-of-gridview-on-button-click-which-is) 

Hope this will helps you.